# css doesn't work in firefox, but in all other browser it does

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a bit of an issue with Firefox(v30). I'm making a site, using jQuery Fullpage scroller and the whole site works in Chrome(v35), IE(11), Opera(v22), but not in firefox. Some of the stylings appear, like the font and colors, but none of the images or the backgrounds and even the Sections are not displaying properly. Could you look at it please, because I have made another site with the Fullpage script and it's working under firefox and I've used the same method everywhere and now it just doesn't want to work. The address is: http://sikitomi.hopto.org/bts

Here is my index file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" lang="en" content="">
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">

    <title>Body Training Solutions</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.fullPage.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" /> -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                loopTop: true,
                loopBottom: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
        <div class="left">
            <p><img src="./img/logo.png" alt=""/></p>
            <p>FULL SITE</p>
            <p>COMING SOON</p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
            <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <h1>UPCOMING EDUCATION COURSES</h1>
        <div class="arrow">
            <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <h1>OUR CLASSES</h1>
        <div class="arrow">
            <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="trx"><img src="./img/trx.png" alt="TRX"/></li>
            <li class="trx"><img src="./img/trigger.png" alt="TriggerPoint"/></li>
            <li class="trx"><img src="./img/ankorr.png" alt="Ankorr"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the style.css I've made:

```
/* Font */

@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'canterbold';
    src: url('canter_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('canter_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('canter_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('canter_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('canter_bold-webfont.svg#canterbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Defaults */

html, body, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, ul
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style: none;
}

img
{
    border: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

p img
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
/* Customisations */

body
{
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'canterbold';
    color: #fff;
}

#section0
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('../img/slide01bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#section0 .left
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 36%;
    height: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10vh;
    font-size: 600%;
}

#section0 p
{
    padding: 2% 0px;
}

#section0 .arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 36%;
    height: 12%;
    text-align: center;
}

#section1
{
    background: url('../img/slide02bg.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}

#section1 h1
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 2%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 8vh;
    font-size: 480%;
}

#section1 .arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 12%;
    text-align: center;
}

#section2
{
    background: url('../img/slide03bg.jpg') center bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

#section2 h1
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 8vh;
    font-size: 480%;
    color: #3c3c3c;
    z-index: 10;
}

#section2 .bg
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    background: url('../img/slide03middle.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#section2 .arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 12%;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
}

#section2 ul
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 37%;
}

#section2 li
{
    width: 33%;
    height: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
}

#section3
{
    background: url('../img/slide04bg.jpg') center bottom;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any help appreciated, because this is really driving me nuts at this stage... :(
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Opening the inspect tools make it work, strange. Curious to see the answer.

Comment: Resizing of any sort works for me. The heights of all the content divs are 0 until there's a resize. I'm assuming something jQuery related it being called to resize the divs on a page resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `doctype` is missing, try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`before the `<html>` tag

Comment: ok now you dropped the opening <html> tag though :) your first 3 lines of code should be

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

Comment: wow. simply wow. this solved it. but don't understand why would this be a problem, since <html> should be accepted as it is (as I read about it). but from now on, this is how I'm going to use it. Thanks a million!

Comment: check this out: http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/doctype.htm and remember to put back the opening <html> tag after the doctype ;)

Comment: got it, thanks. accidentally deleted the line in my happyness :D